# XMPP ios framwoerk Connect not wotking in swift 3

Tags: swift3, xmpp, ejabberd, openfire, xmppframework

I used xmppframewotk ios. connect delegate not working in swift 3. But socket is connected .

Comment: Would you please elaborate your problem with code and in depth ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import XMPPFramework
inherited XMPPRosterDelegate,XMPPStreamDelegate
```

1. `var xmppStream:XMPPStream`!
2. `let xmppRosterStorage = XMPPRosterCoreDataStorage()`
3. `var xmppRoster: XMPPRoster`!

code:

```
func connect() -> Bool {

    if xmppStream == nil {
        xmppStream = XMPPStream()
        xmppStream.addDelegate(self, delegateQueue: DispatchQueue.main)
    }

    if xmppStream.isDisconnected(){

        if !(xmppStream?.isDisconnected())! {
            return true
        }
        xmppStream?.myJID = XMPPJID.init(string: JABBERID)
        xmppStream?.hostName = aHost
        xmppStream?.hostPort = 5222
        xmppStream?.enableBackgroundingOnSocket = true

        do {
            try xmppStream?.connect(withTimeout: XMPPStreamTimeoutNone)
            print("Connection success")
            return true
        } catch {
            print("Something went wrong!")
            return false
        }
    } else {
        return true
    }
}
```